# How To Create An Ik Rig With A Boneset That Isn't Connected

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

I'm trying to create a simple IK rig to make animating for games easier. However due to the bone rotations and it not being connected I encounter issues forcing me to animate in FK.

I found a thread, [How can I apply IK rigging with a different kind of rig](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130589/how-can-i-apply-ik-rigging-with-a-different-kind-of-rig) that explains how to fix my problem however, I'm very confused when reading it. Also as a note I don't want to force connect the bones because it won't import into the game correctly.

[image: None of the bones are connected but still function as a actual rig]

Comment: if you rotate everything 90 degrees all of bones would be connected.

Comment: The goal is to not adjust the existing boneset. Either way I found a solution

Comment: Could you import the rig again with the settings shown by Vklidu? - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/178117/blender-2-81-how-do-i-import-the-rig-correctly/179269#179269

Comment: I stated I don't want to adjust the existing boneset, force connecting children break the boneset on import